# mysqli_query,mysqli_fetch_array and php

Tags: php, mysqli

plz help me to resolve this problem..

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\function\fuction.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\function\fuction.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\function\fuction.php on line 11

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user_id="root";
$password="";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user_id,$password) OR die("not connected.... ");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,'ecommerce') OR die ("not connected...");
?>




<?php
function getbrands()
{
$fetch_brand="SELECT * FROM brands";


        $run=mysqli_query($con,$fetch_brand);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run));

         $brands_id=$row[0];
         $brands_title=$row[1];

         echo "<h4 align='center' style='margin:0px'>

         <a href='ecommerce.php?brands=$brands_id'>$brands_title</a></h4><hr>";


    }



?>
```

Comment: Pass your connection to your function as `getbrands($con)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function getbrands()
{
    global $con;
    $fetch_brand="SELECT * FROM brands";


        $run=mysqli_query($con,$fetch_brand);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run));

         $brands_id=$row[0];
         $brands_title=$row[1];

         echo "<h4 align='center' style='margin:0px'>

         <a href='ecommerce.php?brands=$brands_id'>$brands_title</a></h4><hr>";


    }
?>
```

Comment: thanksss bro.....it works bt there  is fetching problem ....there is no data fetching from the database

Comment: @mukeshkumar For using any variable declared outside of a function, you need to make it global inside your function. And mark the solution as answer If it solved your problem.

Comment: ok i marked....bt wht abt fetchng from database...

Comment: @mukeshkumar try dumping $row in while loop like this `var_dump($row)` and post output in the comment.

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\function\fuction.php on line 13

Comment: after adding var_dump($row ) this error occured

Comment: Where did you add the `var_dump($row);` ?

Comment: while(var_dump($row)=mysqli_fetch_array($run));

Comment: @mukeshkumar Inside while loop means, inside the block of while loop, `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){ var_dump($row); }`

Comment: rray(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(3) "hcl" ["brands_title"]=> string(3) "hcl" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(4) "sony" ["brands_title"]=> string(4) "sony" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "2" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(3) "hcl" ["brands_title"]=> string(3) "hcl" }

Comment: now it can b show like this inside the div where i want to fetch..

Comment: change this line `echo "<h4 align='center' style='margin:0px'><a href='ecommerce.php?brands=$brands_id'>$brands_title</a></h4><hr>";` with `echo "<h4 align='center' style='margin:0px'><a href='ecommerce.php?brands=".$brands_id."'>".$brands_title."</a></h4><hr>";`

Comment: bro nothing changed...same error

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: same error...   
rray(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(3) "hcl" ["brands_title"]=> string(3) "hcl" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(4) "sony" ["brands_title"]=> string(4) "sony" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "2" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(3) "hcl" ["brands_title"]=> string(3) "hcl" }

Comment: It's not the error, just remove the `var_dump($row);`

Comment: it removed all this....bt i want to fetch data from database

Comment: nd nothing is fetching.

Comment: @mukeshkumar Are you new in php? This is the data `array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(3) "hcl" ["brands_title"]=> string(3) "hcl" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(4) "sony" ["brands_title"]=> string(4) "sony" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "2" ["brands_id"]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(3) "hcl" ["brands_title"]=> string(3) "hcl" }` which is being fetched fromt the database.

Comment: yes i m beginner in php....

Comment: @mukeshkumar Please post your full source code in your question.

Comment: ya i know this is fetching from database...bt i only want brand_title is to b fetched nt like the whole information abt that..

Comment: change this `SELECT * FROM brands` with `SELECT brand_title FROM brands` and access it like this `echo $row['brand_title']`

Comment: @mukeshkumar give me access to your source code, If you don't have any problem with that and I will fix the problem.

Comment: <?php
function getbrands()
{
 
 global $con;
 $fetch_brand="SELECT brands_title FROM brands";
  $run=mysqli_query($con,$fetch_brand);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run));
 
      $brands_id=$row[0];
   $brands_title=$row[1];
   
   echo "<h4 align='center' style='margin:0px'>
   
   <a href='ecommerce.php?brands=$brands_id'>$brands_title</a></h4><hr>";
 
 
 }



?>

Comment: <?php
$host="localhost";
$user_id="root";
$password="";
$con =mysqli_connect($host,$user_id,$password) OR die("not connected.... ");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,'ecommerce') OR die ("not connected...");
?>

Comment: @mukeshkumar Please provide me the source code files somehow.

Comment: It's developer.rohitkhatri[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: done...i sent it...check it out

Comment: @mukeshkumar I have replied with fixed source code zip file, please extract the files and use them instead, let me know if you find any trouble.

Comment: bro this all file in encypted form...after extracting all files are crashed

Comment: sorry i got d files....wait i'll check it works or not

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\function\fuction.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\ecommerce.php on line 32

Comment: now this warning is  shown

Comment: @mukeshkumar Please replace `$brands = mysqli_fetch_all();` with `$brands = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: leave it bro...i'll find another way.... thankssssss bro for helping me...m very grateful that u tried ...again thnkxx a lot

Comment: @mukeshkumar If you have teamviewer, I can assist you by remote access, If you don't have any problem with that.

Comment: sorry bro i dnt have

Comment: its ok bro....i'll find another way..